# Combination of Addition and Multiplication of 1 and 0 done 13^12 times to never reach above 3^3^3^3^3

Tags: combinatorics

I have been doing this question for some time.

If the question is asking us to find the combinations of adding and multiplying 1 and 0 why can't it be 1+1+1+1... but it can be 1+1=2 or just 1?

Below is the question:

> Start with 0 and 1. Then do all combinations of adding and multiplying
> 2 of the numbres (with repetition) to get 0, 1, and 2. Repeat this
> step 13¹² more times. Show that the smallest natural numbrer never
> reached is greater than ⁵3 (3 raised to itself 5 times)

Any tips for how to get to the answer or what this question is asking us would be welcome! Thanks.

Comment: After zero steps you have $0,1$.  After one step you have $0+0=0,0+1=1,1+1=2$.  After two steps you have those and $1+2=3, 2\times 2=4$. After three steps you have those and $1+4=5, 3+3=6, 3+4=7, 4+4=8, 3\times 4=12, 4\times4=16$.  And so on.

Comment: Not particularly useful, but the largest number you can reach is $2^{2^{13^{12}-1}}$ which near  $3^{3^{3^{3^{3.01991997}}}}$ is massively larger than $3^{3^{3^{3^3}}}$.  If you cannot see it, the final exponent is about $3.01991997$ rather than $3$.

Comment: missed $3\times3=9$  after three steps in my first comment

Comment: Separate question what is the name of the notation used to represent 3 to itself 5 times. ⁵3?

Comment: It is called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can try to clarify the question.

We begin with a set of $2$ numbers: $0$ and $1$. We then apply addition and multiplication to any two numbers from our set with repetition:

$$0 + 0 = 0 ;~ 0+1 = 1;~1+1=2;~0*0=0;~0*1=0;~1*1=1$$

By doing so we got $3$ numbers: $0$, $1$ and $2$. We now repeat the operation with the new set of numbers. After step $2$ we will get the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. After step $3$ -- $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,16\}$, and this is the first example when we do not get just the set of the first consecutive natural numbers. (Which shows that the pattern is not that obvious.)

Now, consider we did $13^{12}$ such steps. The problem asks the following: show that all the numbers until ⁵3 will be represented in our set after all the steps. (The problem asks to show that the smallest number **not** in the set is greater than ⁵3 which is equivalent.)

Edit: <s>Small hint for the solution: prove that all the numbers up to $2^{2^n}$ will be present after the $(n+2)$-nd step.</s>

Edit 2: As [Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry) pointed out the first edit is incorrect.

Comment: So you are saying that after three steps all the numbers up to $2^{2^2}=16$ will be present.  How do you make $10$? Or $26$ after four steps, or $178$ after five steps or $7391$ after six steps?

Comment: No. The set of numbers after three steps misses both 10 and 11.

Comment: @Henry
Yes, thank you. After the (n+2)-nd step would be correct. I counted from the {0,1,2} step. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you, corrected for (n+2)-nd step. This one is true, if I am not mistaken. (Binary system)

Comment: That edit still does not cover $178$ after five steps, given $2^{2^3}=256$

Comment: @Henry Thank you, you are right. I found the error in my argument.

Comment: Hey, I don’t know if this is how things work around here, but do you have a solution to this problem? Because I have tried to prove the things you have said and I simply cannot find a pattern or rule. If possible can you please send your solution to the question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnhadArora I do not know a full solution as of now. My initial guess was incorrect. Let me think about it once more.

Comment: @DenisGorodkov thanks for your time.